# MVC automatically tags as required. How do I prevent/suppress automatic tagging for validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes, required

I have a model with int fields, such as UserTypeID. I am not using [Required] attribute.

However, the MVC (3.0) generates HTML with required attributes, and the validation message kicks in when I try to submit the form.

Can someone explain the reason and also show how I can suppress the annoying behavior?
In my opinion, the creators should have known better and require EXPLICIT attributes or
configuration for the automatic attributes to kick in.

Or, am I missing some details?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `int` values cannot be null, you need to use nullable integer `int?` instead.